# EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot detect ES version

Tags: elasticsearch, hive

This question has been asked before, but I am using hive instead of spark. So I didn't quite understand how to apply the solution to my problem. So I am posting  my question.
I am learning to connect Elasticsearch with hive and I am using this link.    https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/hive.html

I installed Elasticsearch in my server. I started hive and added the jar file.

```
add jar /path/elasticsearch-hadoop-6.3.2.jar;
```

Then I tried to create a table using the query given in the above link.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table1 (col1 int, col2 string) STORED BY 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler' TBLPROPERTIES('es.resource' = 'warehouse/table1','es.index.auto.create' = 'false');
```

That's when I got this error.

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot detect ES version - typically this happens if the network/Elasticsearch cluster is not accessible or when targeting a WAN/Cloud instance without the proper setting 'es.nodes.wan.only'
```

I tried setting `'es.nodes.wan.only' = 'true'` but it didn't work.
Further search says that executors may not be able to connect to Elasticsearch and I need to change network configuration. But how do I do that? I am new to Elasticsearch. Please help.

Comment: You need to set `es.nodes`in TBLPROPERTIES otherwise how can Hive guess what is (are) the IP(s) of your ES cluster ?

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I don't understand why they didn't give it in the link.